# Start another thread when previous thread finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, windows-store-apps, threadpool

Hi Im working on windows store app and I have page where I need start thread when previous thread finish work. Is there any solution? I find great options but they are for NET. Now Im using ThreadPoolTimer and every thread start at different time but this is not good solution I think there must be better solution.

```
  TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

ThreadPoolTimer DelayTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(
    (source) =>
    {
        // 
        // TODO: Work
        // 

        // 
        // Update the UI thread by using the UI core dispatcher.
        // 
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(
            CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
            () =>
            {
                // 
                // UI components can be accessed within this scope.
                // 

            });

    }, delay);
```

Comment: Research task parallel library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx. Will allow you to chain together tasks like these.

Comment: What makes you think this is not the way to go? You do work on a background thread and then schedule the UI update to execute on the UI thread when that thread is available. This seems like a perfectly reasonable way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the TPL with the ContinueWith statement like this:

```
Task x = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
           DoSomething();
         }
     ).ContinueWith((task) =>
         {
           DoSomething();
         });
```